# Online books on Jyotisha

Tags: astrology, book-recommendation

What are some good books available on Jyotisha online?

I am preferably looking for books for beginners, although any references are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am compiling a brief list of useful books related to astrology both for beginners and for advance users. Some of the books also are in Hindi language, and all the books are directly downloadable  via the link which are in PDF and  MS word format.

- [**Vedic Astrology by SUVRATSUT**](https://archive.org/details/VedicAstrology_201707)  - (MS word)
- [**Vedanta Jyotish (vedic Astrology) - by SUVRATSUT**](https://archive.org/details/VedantaJyotishvedicAstrology) – (MS word)
- [**Study On Vedic Astrology by SUVRATSUT**](https://archive.org/details/StudyOnVedicAstrology) -– (MS word)

  ---
- [**Complete Jyotish Sangraha by SHREE PANDIT SYAMLAL DEV**](https://archive.org/details/CompleteJyotishSangraha) -(Hindi PDF)
- [**Bhartiya Jyotish Sastra By Dixit Part 1**](https://archive.org/details/BhartiyaJyotishSastraByDixitPart1)   – (English PDF)
- [**Collection of  Jyotish books  - many astrology books**](https://archive.org/details/Jyotish)  -(English PDF)
- [**Nadi Pariksha**](https://archive.org/details/nadi_pariksha)  - (Sanskrit with Hindi Translation)

  ---

Hopr that users will find some of these books interesting

Answer (score 2):

[Vedic astrology](http://www.vedicastrologer.org/articles/index.htm#astro) by  PVR Narasimha Rao

There is not a very good collection of books on Astrology for online reads. And if they are there, not many are from validated sources or legal copy.
I have read and listen to the works of PVR Narasimha Rao. He is taking astrology to a new level. This is good for beginners.

There is also other way of learning astrology, which is by reading the case studies.
Barbara Pijan's website will help you in this.
http://www.barbarapijan.com/