# What is the best way to get started with Astrology in Hinduism?

Tags: astrology, book-recommendation

I have been trying to read about it on the internet but it is mostly superficial and out of context. I am planning to commit to buying a book for which I need recommendations.

Comment: http://jyotishvidya.com/ch35.htm Brihat Prashara Hora Shastra is the original genuine book on astrology

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Online books on Jyotisha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12159/online-books-on-jyotisha)

Comment: Also, become active part of Jyotish circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Reading List in Hindu Astrology (Parasari System) or Vedic Astrology

**Introductory texts:**

1. Essentials of Vedic Astrology by Komilla Sutton
2. Light On Life: An Introduction to the Astrology of India by Hart de Fouw and Robert E Svoboda
3. Beneath A Vedic Sky by William R Levacy
4. Learn Think And Predict Through Astrology by C P Arora

**Planets:**

1. Kosthi Dekha by Jyotish Bachaspati (Bengali)
2. Planets in the Signs and Houses: Vedic Astrologer’s Handbook Vol. II by Bepin Behari
3. Scientific Analysis of Horoscope by L R Choudhury
4. Retrograde Planets by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
5. Lunar Nodes by Komilla Sutton

**Houses:**

1. Charisma of Kendra Houses by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
2. Charisma of Trika Houses by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
3. Charisma of Trikone Houses by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
4. Charisma of Upachaya Houses by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
5. Predictive Astrology an Insight by Dinesh Mathur

**Nakshatras:**

1. Nakshatras: The lunar mansions by Dennis Harness
2. Nakshatras: The Stars Beyond the Zodiac by Komilla Sutton
3. Nakshatra Based Predictions Vol I: Planets in padas by K T Subhkaran

**Dasha:**

1. Nakshatra Based Predictions Vol II Dasha Predictions by K T Subhkaran
2. Advanced study of Vimshottari dasha by K K Pathak

**Transit:**

1. Transit of Planets by L R Chawdhri
2. A Text Book of Transit of Planets by O.P. Verma
3. Gochar Phaladeepika by U. S. Pulippani
4. Planets in Transit by Robert Hand (a Western astrology classic, but also useful in Hindu Astrology)

**Connections:**

1. Planetary aspects in Astrology by O. P. Verma
2. Predictive Astrology by Gopesh Kumar Ojha
3. Dispositors in Astrology by J N Bhasin
4. Yogas in Astrology by K S Charak
5. Core Yogas by Ernst Wilhlem

**Miscellaneous Topics**

1. Shodasha Varga by Komilla Sutton
2. Predict with Dashamsha by V. P. Goel
3. Personal Panchanga by Komilla Sutton

**Advanced:**

1. Fortune and misfortune an astrological analysis by K K Pathak
2. Classical predictive techniques Volume I & II by K K Pathak
3. Special Topics in Vedic Astrology Vol 1 & 2 by Alison Bodhani
4. The Art and Practice of Ancient Hindu Astrology Part One & Two by James Braha
5. New Techniques of Predictions (Vol 1-2) by Sheshadri Iyer
6. Astro Sutras by J N Bhasin
7. Hora Shatak by J N Bhasin

**General Practical Astrology:**

1. A Course in Indian Astrology by N E Muthuswami
2. Practical Vedic Astrology by G S Agarwal
3. Jyotish Bicharer Naba Diganta (Vol 1 – 7) by Ranatosh Saha (Bengali)
4. Jyotishe Bhava Bichar by Samiran Mukhopadhyay (Bengali)

**Medical Astrology:**

1. Medical Astrology – a Rational Approach by J N Bhasin
2. Essentials Of Medical Astrology by K S Charak

**Career:**

1. Education and Astrology by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
2. Finance and Profession: a Vedic Approach by Lt. Col. (Retd.) Raj Kumar
3. The Stars and Your Profession by Prem Kumar Sharma
4. Profession through Astrology by O P Verma
5. Astrological Key to Your Career by Alka Vijh
6. Planets and Travel Abroad by M S Mehta

**Relationship:**

1. Understanding Relations the Vedic Astrology Way by Alka Vijh
2. Predicting Marriage by Mridula Trivedi
3. Light on Relationships: The Synastry of Indian Astrology by Hart de Fouw and Robert E Svoboda
4. The Art of Match Making by Gayatri Devi Basudev

**Progeny:**

1. Only First or Last Born Child by Rajbir Singh
2. Adoption by Rajbir Singh

**Remedial:**

1. Remedial Astrology by K K Pathak
2. Power of Nine Gemstones by Bhavay Kaushik

**Classics:**

1. Brihat Parasar Hora Sastra by Sage Parasara
2. Phaladeepika by Mantreshwara
3. Saravali by Kalyana Varma
4. Brihat Jataka by Barahamihir
5. Satya Jataka by Satyacharya
6. Jataka Parijata by Vaidyanatha Dikshita

**Useful KP Astrology Books:**

1. Nadi Astrology Marriage and Relationships by Umang Taneja
2. Nadi Astrology and Professions by Umang Taneja
3. Nadi Astrology Accurate Predictive Methodology by Umang Taneja
4. KP Reader Vol. 3 by K S Krishnamurti

Apart from this list, two other reading lists on Vedic astrology are also available.

1. A Reading List on Vedic Astrology by Hank Friedman.
   https://www.soulhealing.com/vedicstarbook.htm
2. Recommended Reading List by Vedic Astrologer Shyamsundara Dasa
   https://shyamasundaradasa.com/jyotish/study/b

Comment: Brilliant List Sir! But i really wanted to know when you actually started learning Jyotish Shastra, how much time did it take to get a good grip on concepts, did you learn it under a Guru, and was it a part-time hobby or did you take it up as a full time profession?

Comment: @Rāmachandra You asked a very good question. To get a good grasp on the subject, you need to study it for at least 10 years. Yes, I was introduced to the subject by my guru astrologer P. K. Shastri. It is my hobby.